# Add an extra column to ndarray in python

Tags: numpy

I have a ndarray as follows.

```
feature_matrix = [[0.1, 0.3], [0.7, 0.8], [0.8, 0.8]]
```

I have a position ndarray as follows.

```
position = [10, 20, 30]
```

Now I want to add the position value at the beginning of the feature_matrix as follows.

```
[[10, 0.1, 0.3], [20, 0.7, 0.8], [30, 0.8, 0.8]]
```

I tried the answers in this: [How to add an extra column to an numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486294/how-to-add-an-extra-column-to-an-numpy-array)

```
E.g.,

feature_matrix = np.concatenate((feature_matrix, position), axis=1)
```

However, I get the error saying that;

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Please help me to resolve this prblem.

Comment: Just use `np.column_stack`.

Comment: Did you try to adapt my answer to your previous question?  `np.insert(feature_matrix,0,[10,20,30],ax‌​is=1)`;  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065339/how-to-insert-list-of-ndarray-lists-to-a-newndarray-in-python

Comment: Yes, I get SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier. that comes for axis part.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an extra column to an numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486294/how-to-add-an-extra-column-to-an-numpy-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved my problem. I used np.column_stack.

```
feature_matrix = [[0.1, 0.3], [0.7, 0.8], [0.8, 0.8]]
position = [10, 20, 30]
feature_matrix = np.column_stack((position, feature_matrix))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the shape of the `position` array which is incorrect regarding the shape of the `feature_matrix`.

```
>>> feature_matrix
array([[ 0.1,  0.3],
       [ 0.7,  0.8],
       [ 0.8,  0.8]])

>>> position 
array([10, 20, 30])

>>> position.reshape((3,1))
array([[10],
       [20],
       [30]])
```

The solution is (with `np.concatenate`):

```
>>> np.concatenate((position.reshape((3,1)), feature_matrix), axis=1)
array([[ 10. ,   0.1,   0.3],
       [ 20. ,   0.7,   0.8],
       [ 30. ,   0.8,   0.8]])
```

But `np.column_stack` is clearly great in your case !